# Tomcat and updated flex services-config.xml

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat, grails

I need to update the flex/services-config.xml that lists the amf channels in Tomcat without restarting Tomcat or using the Manager.

Is this possible ? Is there some command I can use to reload the app without restarting Tomcat.

I am using
Tomcat 6

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 2):

In `services-config.xml`, you can set an automatic redeploy interval that will look for configuration changes:

```
<system>
    <redeploy>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <!-- Change to fit your requirements -->
        <watch-interval>20</watch-interval>
        <watch-file>{context.root}/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml</watch-file>
        <watch-file>{context.root}/WEB-INF/flex/proxy-config.xml</watch-file>
        <watch-file>{context.root}/WEB-INF/flex/remoting-config.xml</watch-file>                       
        <watch-file>{context.root}/WEB-INF/flex/messaging-config.xml</watch-file>                                  
        <watch-file>{context.root}/WEB-INF/flex/data-management-config.xml</watch-file> 
        <touch-file>{context.root}/WEB-INF/web.xml</touch-file>
    </redeploy>
</system>
```

You will have to manually redeploy at least once for this to take effect, though